# SQL - Needed fields in output are unavailable in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

We have two tables:

1. tbl_serviceData(id is primary key)
2. tbl_CustomerData (s_id is foreign key)

Now as shown in pictures for cust_name = kiran, the outout is okey, but what I required is I want those services also in the name of that customer though he has not used them.

For example, kiran has used services like milk, water, coffee, lunch and he paid for it that's right but I want all remaining services in the output having zero value. For example, kiran have not used Breakfast, tea and dinner services, but still I want them in output having zero value.
Remember that in `tbl_Customerdata` table the breakfast, tea and dinner services are not available in the name of kiran.

[image: tbl_Servicedata and tbl_CustomerData]

---

[image: output and required output]

Comment: Google "SQL Joins", look at the images results.  If you haven't figured it out at that point, come back and update the question with what you tried and tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service where you simply state your requirements and a host of programmers deliver free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

```
with T
    as (select C.S_Id, C.Paid
    from tbl_CustomerData as C
    where c.Cust_Name = @CUST_NAME)
select
        S.SERVICESS as Servicess,
        isnull(T.Paid,0) as Paid
    from tbl_Servicedata as S
        left join T as T on T.S_Id = S.ID
    order by isnull(T.Paid,0) desc
```

Comment: Dear, rocks! Your option displays all the options are not. Because you are applying for in A.SRVC tbl_CustomerData table that stores are not all the values SERVICESS.

Comment: Извини. Вот правильный вариант

Comment: with T
 as (select C.S_Id, C.Paid
 from tbl_CustomerData as C
 where c.Cust_Name = @CUST_NAME)
select
  S.SERVICESS as Servicess,
  isnull(T.Paid,0) as Paid
 from tbl_Servicedata as S
  left join T as T on T.S_Id = S.ID
 order by isnull(T.Paid,0) desc

Comment: Also. This is DWH or OLTP? If this is not the data warehouse and operational business application, duplicate the wrong words in the tables in the columns "SERVICESS" and "SRVC". You need to make one more table directory, stored in the MDM these names. If the table "Servicess" is itself a reference. Then, in the table "CustomerData" need to remove the column "SRVC". This creates redundant data anomalies and problems in the event of a change of a name in the attribute "SERVICESS". To communicate enough attribute "S_Id". Knowing the communication "S_Id", you always get the value "SERVICESS".

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN in this Case,

```
select A.SRVC, COALESCE(A.Paid, 0) Paid 
from tbl_CustomerData A left join tbl_Servicedata B on (A.S_Id = B.ID) 
where A.Cust_Name = @CUST_NAME
```